# How to Fetch Data from SqliteDatabase to Calendar Adapter?

Tags: android

**WHy when i use this in CalendarAdapter it marked as error?**

Can you help me with this error?

```
 public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
        DbFertility db = new DbFertility(this); <=== (why when i use (this) in Calednar Adapater it marked as an error?
                    db.open();
                    int cycle = Integer.parseInt(db.getCycle(l));
                    int period = Integer.parseInt(db.getPeriod(l));
                    int date1 = Integer.parseInt(db.getPeriod(l));
                    db.close();}

    public DbHelper{

        public String getCycle(long l){
            String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_PERIOD_ID, KEY_CYCLE_LENGHT,KEY_PERIOD_LENGHT,KEY_FIRST_DAY_OF_PERIOD};
            Cursor c =  getOurDatabase().query(TABLE_PERIOD, columns, KEY_PERIOD_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
            if(c != null){
                c.moveToFirst();
                String cycle = c.getString(1);
                return cycle;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public String getPeriod(long l){
            String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_PERIOD_ID, KEY_CYCLE_LENGHT,KEY_PERIOD_LENGHT,KEY_FIRST_DAY_OF_PERIOD};
            Cursor c =  getOurDatabase().query(TABLE_PERIOD, columns, KEY_PERIOD_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
            if(c != null){
                c.moveToFirst();
                String period = c.getString(2);
                return period;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The Error is : The Constructor DbFertility(CalendarAdapter) is undefined.
Expected Output: i want to fetch data from DbHelper.

Comment: Please specify which is the error you are getting.

Comment: When i use (this) in DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this) in calendarAdapter  the this will become error

Comment: But what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the base class of your `Dbfertility` but if it extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` you may need an Android `Context`. It is difficult to guess without seeing the code of the constructor of the class you want to instantiate.

From what I see from your code your `DbFertility` constructor must be defined with either a `BaseAdapter` or with a `CalendarAdapter`. If the error is constructor not defined you need to create this constructor in class:

```
public DbFetility(final BaseAdapter adapter){
    // do init here
}
```

I am not sure if you know this but when you use `this` in a class or a method it refers to the current class that you are in. In your case it refers to the `CalendarAdapter`.

Also it is probably a formatting issue but the code of your `CalendarAdpater` seems wrong on the lines that follow the creation of your `db` attribute. They should be in a method.

If my answer doesn't help please consider providing the missing code parts otherwise it is difficult to figure out what is wrong.